# Clear input default value on focus and fill the value back if its null on blur

Tags: jquery

I need it to clear the default input value on focus, and bring the value back if the value is empty on blur. Here is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function toggleText(selector, value) {
        $(selector).focus(function() {
            if ($(this).val == value) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });
        $(selector).blur(function() {
            if ($(this).val == '') {
                $(this).val(value);
            }
        });
    }
    toggleText('input[name="first-name"]', 'First name...');
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: it is not compatible with IE at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `$(this).val()`, not `$(this).val`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function toggleText(selector, value) {
        $(selector).focus(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == value) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });
        $(selector).blur(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).val(value);
            }
        });
    }
    toggleText('input[name="first-name"]', 'First name...');
});
```

**Edit:**

But I think it's better this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function toggleText(selector) {
        $(selector).focus(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == $(this)[0].defaultValue) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });
        $(selector).blur(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).val($(this)[0].defaultValue);
            }
        });
    }
    toggleText('input[name="first-name"]');
});
```

you can use `$(this).defaultValue()` if you use [this plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/default-value).